# PG_Dump returning 'too many command-line arguments (first is "databasename")'

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to retrieve the schema from a production database and am using the below script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -f -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L xxxx:domain.com:xxx servername sleep 10

echo 'password'

pg_dump --port xxxx --username johndoe --host localhost -W password --file schemadump.sql --schema-only --no-privileges --no-owner databasename
```

however it is returning the error

> pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "databasename").

I've tried a few variations but still getting the same error. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You can not specify a password with the `-W` option. That only controls the _prompting_ for a password

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to do the trick though I've another problem regarding access but that's for another day. Thanks again for the help. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of `-W` flag which:

> Force pg_dump to prompt for a password before connecting to a database.

It skips command and expects password input.

If you want to write one-line script for pg_dump with authorization use a temporary variable instead of flags in the following way:

> PGPASSWORD="password" pg_dump --port xxxx --username johndoe --host localhost --file schemadump.sql --schema-only --no-privileges --no-owner databasename